# ArrayList.add() causing OutOfMemory error?

Tags: android, arraylist, memory-management, out-of-memory, addition

For the first time today, I've met an OutOfMemory Error. I'm trying to calculate moving averages out of some data into an ArrayList, and had a crash at the first .add() step. The method is shown below

```
  public ArrayList<Long> getNdaySMA(List<HistoricalQuote> history, int range){
    long sum =0;
    long SMA = 0;
    ArrayList<Long> SMAs = new ArrayList<Long>();
    //realRange is made due to the differences in defining "range in calculation vs speech
    //a 10 day range for day 9 is actually from prices of day0 to day9, inclusive
    int realRange =range-1;

    //First step, add in placeholder 0s for the days within the range that have no value
    //so if 10 day range, we have 0-> 9
    for (int i=0;i<i+realRange;i++){
        SMAs.add(i,0L);
    }

    //Next, actually calculate the SMAs for i.e. day 10
    for (int i =0;i<history.size();i++){
        //should be k<10, 0......9 = 10 days
        for(int k=i+realRange;k==i;k--){
            //Sum first from k=i+range-1 , go down to i.
            //This should give us a value of RANGE
            sum +=history.get(k).getClose().longValue();


        }
        //after summing up, we add calculate SMA and add it to list of SMAs
        SMA = sum/range;
        //we add the corresponding SMA to index i+range, made up of values calculated from before it
        //to excel
        SMAs.add(i+realRange,SMA);
        sum =0;
    }

    return SMAs;
}
```

The stacktrace is as follows

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:154)
                                                                at com.xu.investo.MethodDatabase.getNdaySMA(MethodDatabase.java:46)
```

Where Line 46 refers to

```
SMAs.add(i,0L);
```

Is this error occuring due to the use of the Long number format? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It is not problem of adding long your loop is infinite loop it is never ending check condition carefully  "i<i+realRange" making it infinite loop

Comment: your problem resolved?

Comment: Yeah I found the solution, its the second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like infinite loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<i+realRange;i++)
```

`i` will always be less then `i+realRange` for `realRange` greater then zero:

Answer (score 0):

I think I've identified the problem.

I may have created an infinite loop at this line

```
 for (int i=0;i<i+realRange;i++){
    SMAs.add(i,0L);
}
```